# How is a .net website's bin folder populated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

We're trying to compile a traditional (very complex) app in 64 bit (it's been 32 bit for years). The Solution has a website and under that website there's a bin folder and my question is how is that populated? I go to bin->add reference and point to the correct 64-bit files but after I build the solution several of those files are being replaced by their 32-bit counterparts. How is that possible? There's no .csproj file for the website that specifies where the files in the bin folder come from so how can I force it to get the right files? And when I change the files using references->add no changes are pended so I have no idea where it's looking to find out the source of those .dlls.

Comment: Maybe some screenshots would help.  Or maybe you need to describe your project more fully.  It's hard to follow what you have.

Comment: If that's the old ASP.NET Web Site project type, you have to create new ASP.NET Web Application project(s) and cut/paste code over when possible. That project type has far too many disadvantages now.